# AWS Lambda Session Overlap

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm new with using AWS Lambda, so apologies if my question seems elementary. Has anyone experienced a session overlap on their Lambda function?

I have a lambda function, in Node, that processes a users payment. Upon receiving confirmation of payment from a 3rd-party payment processor, the function will activate the users account and generate a new institutional email for the user and save it as new primary email/username.

It works without an issue most of the time. However, I have a couple of instances where the details from one transaction bleeds over the other. For example

| User | Jane Doe | John Doe |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Trx. date | 2023-06-27 11:20:20 | 2023-06-27 11:20:23 |
| Generated Email | jane.doe@institute.com | john.doe@institute.com |
| Saved Email | john.doe@institute.com | john.doe@institute.com |

Current Code Structure:

payment.js

```js
const {googleCreateUser,googleGetUser} = require('./google-account');

async function changetoGmail(registration_id){
    return new Promise (async(resolve, reject) => {
        try{
            pool.query(`
            SELECT category, @user_id := id_user_tbl as table1 FROM registration where id = ?;
            SELECT * FROM users where id = @user_id;
            `,[registration_id],
            async (err, res)=>{
                if(err){
                    reject(
                        JSON.stringify({ message: err })
                    )
                }else{

                    let curr_email = res[1][0].email_address;
                    if(curr_email.includes('@institution.com')){
                        reject(JSON.stringify({
                            message:"Users already has email"
                        }))        
                    }else{
                        await processGAccount(res[0][0].user_id)
                        .then(
                            (value) => {resolve(JSON.stringify({message: value}))},
                            (error) => {reject (JSON.stringify({message: 'Unexpected error occurs. Error: ' + error}))}
                        )
                    }


                }
            })

        }catch (e){
            console.log(e)
            reject (
                JSON.stringify({
                    message: '[ged-sesd] - An error occured. Error: ' + e
                })
            )
        }


    })    
}

async function processGAccount(user_id){
    return new Promise (async (resolve, reject) => {
        try{
            /*
            Desc: Get user info by given field
            */
            function getUser(field,value){
                return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    pool.query(`SELECT * FROM users where {field} = ?;`,[value],
                    (err, res)=>{
                        if(err){
                            reject(
                                JSON.stringify({ message: err })
                            )
                        }else{
                            resolve(res);
                        }
                    })
                })
            }

            /*
            Desc: Update user email
            */
            function saveEmail(oldemail,newemail,user_id){
                return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
                    try{
                        pool.query(`
                            UPDATE users SET email_address=?, email_address2 = ? where id = ?;
                            SELECT * FROM users where id = ?;
                            `,
                        [newemail,oldemail,user_id,user_id],
                        (err,res) => {
                            if(err){
                                reject(
                                    JSON.stringify({ message: '[GED001] - An error occured while executing the query. Error: ' + err })
                                )
                            }else{
                                let detail = {user:res[1][0],old_email:oldemail,new_email:newemail}

                                resolve(detail);
                            }
                        })
                    }catch (e){
                        console.log(e)
                        reject (
                            JSON.stringify({
                                message: e
                            })
                        )
                    }
                })
            }

            // Function to update cognito attribute during updating of user profile.
            function updateUserAttribute(email, username) {
                return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    let params = {
                        UserAttributes:[
                                {
                                    Name: 'email',
                                    Value: email
                                },
                                {
                                    Name: 'preferred_username',
                                    Value: email
                                },
                                {
                                    Name: 'email_verified',
                                    Value: 'true'
                                }
                            ],
                        UserPoolId: userPoolId,
                        Username: username
                    }
                    cognitoISP.adminUpdateUserAttributes(params, (err, data) => err ? reject(err) : resolve(data))
                })
            }

            // Function to set a temporary password to a user
            function setTemporaryPassword(username) {
                return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    // character set for temporary password
                    let chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_.-@#ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP1234567890',
                        tempPassword = ''
                    for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                        let index = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length)
                        tempPassword += chars[index]
                    }
                    if(process.env.DEBUGTRUE){
                        tempPassword +='1_a'
                    }


                    let params = {
                        Password: tempPassword.toString(),
                        Permanent: false,
                        UserPoolId: userPoolId,
                        Username: username
                    }
                    cognitoISP.adminSetUserPassword(params, (err, data) => err ? reject(err) : resolve(tempPassword))
                })
            }



            let user = await getUser('id',user_id);
            let password = 'Password@1234';
            let curr_email = user[0].email_address;

            //generate new email
            new_email = await newEmail(user[0].first_name,user[0].middle_name,user[0].last_name)

            //check if email already exists
            let email_comparison = await getUser('email_address',new_email);
            

            let gAccount = await googleGetUser(new_email);

            if(gAccount.length == 0){
                await googleCreateUser(user[0].first_name,user[0].last_name,new_email,password,user[0].email_address)
                .then(
                    async (value)=>{
                            let message = `<html>
                            <body>
                                <table width="100%" height="100%" style="min-width:348px" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" lang="en">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr height="32" style="height:32px">
                                            <td></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr align="center">
                                            <td>
                                            <div><div></div></div>
                                                <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="padding-bottom:20px;max-width:616px;min-width:220px">
                                                    <tbody>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td width="8" style="width:8px"></td>
                                                            <td>
                                                                <div style="border-style:solid;border-width:thin;border-color:#dadce0;border-radius:8px;padding:40px 20px" align="center">
                                                                    <img src="https://logo.png" width="74" height="auto" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-bottom:16px">
                                                                    <div style="border-bottom:thin solid #dadce0;color:rgba(0,0,0,0.87);line-height:32px;padding-bottom:24px;text-align:center;word-break:break-word">
                                                                        <div style="font-size:24px">Welcome to your new Google Account for institution.com</div>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                    <div style="font-family:Roboto-Regular,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:14px;color:rgba(0,0,0,0.87);line-height:20px;padding-top:20px;text-align:left">
                                                                        <p>Hi {user[0].first_name} {user[0].last_name},</p>
                                                                        <p>Welcome to your new Google Account!</p>
                                                                        <p>Sign in to your Google Account (www.gmail.com) to access the Google services. If your organization has Google Workspace, Google services may include business-grade versions of Google Drive, Gmail, and other Google services you can use to collaborate with your team.</p>
                                                                        
                                                                        <table style="font-family:Roboto-Regular,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:14px;color:rgba(0,0,0,0.87);line-height:20px;margin-top:20px;">
                                                                            <tbody>
                                                                                <tr><td style="font-weight:bold">Username: </td><td>{new_email}</td></tr>
                                                                                <tr><td style="font-weight:bold">Password: </td><td>{password}</td></tr>
                                                                            </tbody>
                                                                        </table>
                                                                        <p>To keep your account secure, sign in after 15 Minutes and the reset password provided for your account to take effect.</p>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td width="8" style="width:8px"></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr height="32" style="height:32px">
                                            <td></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </body>
                        </html>`
                
                        let subject = `Welcome to institution.com Google Account`
                
                        await email_user(message,subject,curr_email);
                    },
                    (error) => {reject (JSON.stringify({message: 'Unexpected error occurs. Error: ' + error}))}

                )
            }

            //Update user record
            saveEmail(user[0].email_address,new_email,user_id)
            .then(
                async (value) => {
                    let user = value.user;
                    //Update cognito record
                    await updateUserAttribute( value.new_email, user.sub)
                    .then(
                        (value) => {
                            //Update Password
                            setTemporaryPassword(user.sub)
                            .then(
                                (value) => {
                                    
                                    //Lets send some message
                                    
                                    let message=`<html>
                                        <body>
                                        <p>Good Day,</p>
                                            <p>This is to give you a New Portal Account, {new_email}, and a temporary password is <b style="color:rgb(23, 28, 143);">{value}</b></p>
                                        </body>
                                    </html>`

                                    let subject = 'Portal Account Temporary Password';

                                    email_user(message,subject,new_email)
                                    .then(
                                        (value)=>{ resolve(JSON.stringify({message:"Account Created"})) },
                                        (error) => {reject (JSON.stringify({message: 'Unexpected error occurs. Error: ' + error}))}
                                    )
                                },
                                (error) => {reject (JSON.stringify({message: 'Unexpected error occurs. Error: ' + error}))}
                            )
                        },
                        (error) => {reject (JSON.stringify({message: 'Unexpected error occurs. Error: ' + error}))}
                    )

                },
                (error) => {reject (JSON.stringify({message: 'Unexpected error occurs. Error: ' + error}))}
            )
            

        }catch (e){
            console.log(e)
            reject (
                JSON.stringify({
                    message: '[ged-sesd] - An error occured. Error: ' + e
                })
            )
        }
    })
    
}

function email_user(message,subject,email_address) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            const source_email = process.env.SESEMAIL
            const ses = new AWS.SES({ apiVersion: '2010-12-11' })
            const obj = {
                Destination: {
                    ToAddresses: [email_address]
                },
                Message: {
                    Body: {
                        Html: {
                            Charset: 'UTF-8',
                            Data:message

                        },
                        Text: {
                            Charset: 'UTF-8',
                            Data: subject
                        }
                    },
                    Subject: {
                        Charset: 'UTF-8',
                        Data: subject
                    }
                },
                Source: source_email
            }

            const sendEmail = ses.sendEmail(obj).promise()

            sendEmail
                .then(data => {
                    console.log(data)
                    resolve(
                        JSON.stringify({
                            message: 'Email successfully submitted to SES.'
                        })
                    )
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error)
                    reject(
                        JSON.stringify({
                            message: error
                        })
                    )
                })
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(error)
            reject(
                JSON.stringify({
                    message: error
                })
            )
        }
    })
}

/*
Desc: Compose email_address
*/
function newEmail(firstname,middlename,lastname,id=null){
    firstname_array = firstname.split(' ');

    let new_email = "";
    new_email += firstname_array[0];

    if(firstname_array.length > 1 && (firstname_array[0]).length < 4){
        new_email += firstname_array[1];
    }
    new_email += '.'+lastname.toLowerCase();
    new_email = new_email.normalize("NFD").replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "") + '@institution.com'
    new_email = new_email.replace(" ","");

    return new_email.toLowerCase();
}
```

google-account.js

```js
const {google} = require('googleapis');
const key = require('./redacted.json');



exports.googleCreateUser = async (firstname, lastname, email,password) => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        try{
            const jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(
                key.client_email,
                null,
                key.private_key,
                ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.security'],
                'admin@institution.com',
              );
            
            await jwtClient.authorize();

            const admin = google.admin({version: 'directory_v1', auth: jwtClient});
            const user = {
                name: {
                  givenName: firstname,
                  familyName: lastname
                },
                password: password,
                primaryEmail: email,
                changePasswordAtNextLogin:true
              };
            
              await admin.users.insert({resource: user})
              .then(
                (value) => {resolve(value)},
                (error) => {
                  reject (JSON.stringify({message: '[g-ce-002] - Unexpected error occurs. Error: ' + error}))
                }

              )          
        }catch (e) {
            console.log('[g-ce-001] -  An unexpected occured. Error: ' + e)
            reject(
                JSON.stringify({
                    message: '[g-ce-001] -  An unexpected occured. Error: ' + e
                })
            )
        }
    })
};

exports.googleGetUser = async (email) => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        try{
            const jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(
                key.client_email,
                null,
                key.private_key,
                ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.security'],
                'admin@institution.com',
              );
            
            await jwtClient.authorize();

            const account = {
                userKey: email,
                viewType: 'admin_view',
                projection: 'basic',
              };

            const admin = google.admin({version: 'directory_v1', auth: jwtClient});

            
              await admin.users.get(account)
              .then(
                (value) => {resolve(value)},
                (error) => {resolve([])}

              )
        }catch(e){
            console.log('[g-ge-001] -  An unexpected occured. Error: ' + e)
            reject(
                JSON.stringify({
                    message: '[g-ge-001] -  An unexpected occured. Error: ' + e
                })
            )
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: What do you _want_ to happen?

Comment: Hi @JohnRotenstein, is there a way I can prevent this overlap on data? I know that the issue is minimal, but it would be great if I can eliminate this issue.

Comment: Are you saying that you would like each Lambda function to wait for any previous execution of the function before it starts?

Comment: It's not possible to share session states with other lambda invocations unless those values defined outside of the lambda entry point. Can share the complete code of your lambda implementation?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run AWS Lambda functions such that **only one Lambda function runs at any time** and any other invocations should wait before the next one is run, then:

- Set the [Reserved Concurrency](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-concurrency.html) of the function to `1`. Reserved concurrency is the maximum number of concurrent instances you want to allocate to your function.
- Set the **Batch Size** of the trigger to `1` to ensure only a single message is sent to the Lambda function. You don't mention what triggers your Lambda function, so this might not required.

To learn more about AWS Lambda concurrency, I recommend this series of articles: [Operating Lambda: Performance optimization – Part 1 | AWS Compute Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/operating-lambda-performance-optimization-part-1/)